# How to use Ant Design Menu component

Tags: antd

I'm using Ant Design menu component; everything goes well until the page is refreshing.
Then, the menu selected item back to the top one.

How can I configure the selected item of the menu (to show the user where he is on the page) based on the page he actually in?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: using React 15, react-router-dom

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/menu/) you can use the `selectedKeys` property of the menu.

e.g.

```
class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: ['home']
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu selectedKeys={this.state.selected}>
        <Menu.Item key="home">Home</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```